# How to get the row index after filtering data in Excel 2010 via C#

Tags: c#, excel

I meet a problem:There are many data in an Excel sheet  and I need add comment in the specified rows by filter.

Unfortunately,there is no unique column in the sheet except row index by default.The question is how to get the row index?Any help will be appreciated.

**Code**

```
    public static void FilterExcelByValue(string filePath, int columnIndex,string val)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        app.Visible = true;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook = app.Workbooks.Open(filePath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet workSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workBook.ActiveSheet;

        Range range = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)workSheet.UsedRange;
        range.Select();
        range.Activate();
        range.AutoFilter(columnIndex, val, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues, Type.Missing, true);
        Range visibleCells = range.SpecialCells(
                           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible,
                           Type.Missing);
        foreach (Range area in visibleCells.Areas)
        {
            foreach (Range row in area.Rows)
            {
               //Add logic

            }
        }


    }
```

The filtered table like this below:

**Index     Data

  7          0310939

  9          0311572

  10      0312079

  15      0312900

  19      0313530**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the defect and thanks Alex,I will post the solution for someone who meets the same issue in the furture:

```
        Range range = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)workSheet.UsedRange.Columns[columnIndex, Type.Missing];
        range.Select();
        range.Activate();
        range.AutoFilter(1, val, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues, Type.Missing, true);
        Range visibleCells = range.SpecialCells(
                           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible,
                           Type.Missing);
        foreach (Range area in visibleCells.Areas)
        {
            foreach (Range row in area.Rows)
            {
                Range filteredCell = (Range)row.Cells[1, 1];
                if (filteredCell == null || filteredCell.Value2.ToString() != val)
                    continue;
                int index = row.Row;
                //Console.WriteLine("Index:" + index);
                int columnNo = workSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
                workSheet.Cells[index, columnNo] = "Add Comments";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add worksheet formula `=Row()` in all cells in some specified Column; the value in that Column indicates row index. Hope this will help. Best regards,

Comment: Thanks Alex,I have gotten the right index by using Range.Row,but there is still a question:why get "AutoFilter method of Range class failed"  error in merged range when using range.AutoFilter(columnIndex, FilterList, Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues, Type.Missing, true);,do you have any advise?

Comment: Sorry, but it's hard to tell without knowing the entire data set you run this operation on. Best regards,

Comment: Thanks for your help.I have fixed the defect by choosing an individual column as filtered range,it seems the "range.AutoFilter " method can't filter merged range.